# How can I survive my first night?

Tags: unturned

Quite often I find myself dying quickly. Just walking in a town scavenging for supplies quickly attracts zombies, and since it's near impossible to shake off zombies, and it takes so many hits from my fists to kill them, I end up quickly dying.

Is there some basics I should understand if I want to survive my first night?

Comment: To fight zombies i like to use the kite strategy, just try to find one isolate from the others and then keep hitting and going back, hitting and going back. Usually works and this way you kill the zombie without taking damage. Always try to "clean" the area and then go for scavenging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple hard-learned single-player hints for the first day (or days if you're like me and took a few tries)

edit: found a couple more tricks which makes life a bit easier, so re-writing this to be a bit more detailed.

(To avoid saying "in the current version" every time, this was written Aug 2014, pre-v3. In the future mileage may vary)

Rule 0: Zombies have a fairly defined detection radius. It's never a bad idea to work around the outside of the town, letting a single one "find" you, and taking them out before moving on to the next one. It is almost always a bad idea to run through town triggering multiple zombies to chase you. (Or using a firearm, in most cases - the sound can easily bring more zombies than you can handle.)

Rule 0a: Zombies either respawn very slowly or not at all, *until you disconnect*. Then, everyone respawns. This means you want to disconnect/restart as little as possible, and you want to be in a safe space (for beginning the game, away from civilization) when you do disconnect. When night falls, the best thing to do is retreat to wilderness and just wait it out (I tab to another window and wait for light). Items in town *do* respawn, so being able to safely ransack the cleaned-out town multiple times is *huge*.

OK, so now, let's get you started.

Step 1: You need a melee weapon. Anything will do - golf club, baseball bat, frying pan. Right now you do not have the luxury of being picky. You're going to have to fight the first few zombies with your fists, and it sucks. You want something swingable ASAP. Sadly, there's a bit of a catch-22 here. You need a weapon to efficiently kill zombies, but all the weapons are surrounded by zombies. Best advice I have is work around the outside and check the buildings on the outskirts and hope you get lucky.

Important: right now, you can carry *exactly* four things (and realistically should only carry three to avoid shuffling inventory around). So ignore anything that isn't going to keep you alive for the next three minutes. The one exception is clothes (since you can wear them and that doesn't take up a space).

Step 2: You need a pack. Again, beggars can't be choosers - it's nice to get the Alice Pack (or even a Rucksack), but even the basic schoolbag and it's four extra slots makes your life *much* easier. Now that you have a weapon, cleaning out the town is much simpler - trigger zombie, wait for it to approach, right click on it's head to power-attack, step back and repeat till it dies (most weapons will kill a zombie with one power attack headshot, but better safe than zombie food).

Step 3: Food and water, and "shelter". Once you have a decent weapon and a pack, you're in decent shape. But finding non-moldy food and water is tricky and the lack of either will kill you just as good. So, we need to start finding secure sources for both.

I have "shelter" in quotes because in single player a safe haven is "anywhere the zombies aren't, and that I can find again". I usually pick an overlook for whatever town I'm in - far enough away that the respawn doesn't swamp me in zombies (right now I log in, kill a single guy, and I'm good), but that I can easily find from the town.

But here's what you're looking for with your new pack:

a) A canteen. (Or a water bottle and a can, which lets you craft one). Thirst really sucks until you have one of these, and then it's trivial. Canteens hold water and are *refillable* at any source of water (ocean counts!). So, you fill up a canteen, wander around, and when you get thirsty you find the sea, refill, drink, refill again until Thirst = 0.

b) Seeds. The wiki is a bit misleading here, talking about fertilizer and such. Food is pretty straightforward - pick up some veggies (moldy is perfectly fine). Craft them into seeds. (Fresh veggies give you two, moldy gives one). Go to your shelter area, plan them in the ground - the game will tell you where you can or can't, but pretty much anywhere grassy works. Go about your day, come back in a bit. (I haven't timed it exactly, but the grow time is *crazy short* - under a day. Harvest, pick up your now fresh veggie, craft it into seeds, replant. In short order you'll have more food than you know what to do with.  An added bonus here is that planted food appears to survive disconnect/reconnection, which means even if you die you've got a garden waiting for you when you return.

--

Now, the big question: can you get this all done your first night? There's a lot of luck-of-the-drops here. There's enough melee weapons that you should be able to find *something*. Moldy food is pretty common, so getting a garden running is a safe bet for day 1. Canteens are rare-ish (and water in general, I find), so pick up any you find (even pre-backpack!). Backpacks are hit-and-miss. Sometimes there's none, and sometimes every house has one. I'd call my day 1 a success if I find a decent weapon, get a couple seeds in the ground, and find either a pack or a canteen. Once I have both, life gets so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my strategy.

As soon as you spawn, search for a weapon. It can go from a baseball bat to a gun. You do not have any other choice than getting somewhere where there are zombies, thats where the loot is. As soon as you have a weapon you can start cleaning the area (if it wasnt already done with a painfully long and intense moment of punching the undeads) and then find other kind of loot (food, ammo, clothes, etc).

If you cannot find a weapon, try to get in a car, one that is not smoking if possible. Some of them still have gas in them so you can try to kill a bunch of zombies by driving on their face. This is a bit risky because there is not always gas and if there are, its not a lot, but you can easily kill a lot of zombies that way. You can also outrun them if you want, but you lose potential loot.

Once you've got some gear and a good backpack (if you find one), find somewhere where you can build a base. I usually go to one of those farms near one of the town (unfortunatly I do not know any other way to give their position :/ Thats a strategy I developped a few days ago, I am still discovering the game). Those places are not too big and are easy to defend. Plus, you can grow food there by taking seeds from moldy vegetables.

Fortify the place to get used to the game then after that you might want to consider going in multiplayer to get some action or find some fri4end and build the ultimate zombie fortress!

I hope this helps!

Comment: My problem is when I get a gun, it inevitably seems that I run out of bullets after 5-6 shots, and makes me defenseless once again.

Comment: Melee weapons are the best. I would recommend you to only use ranged weapons in case of an emergency because it generates a lot of noise and you end up losing a lot more bullets than planned.

Answer (score 0):

My strategy in desperate times.

Sometimes, this is your only option. Especially if you cannot find a weapon.
Run straight through the middle of the town, collecting all the zombies (I know, you're about to give up here, but keep reading) And keep them a fair distance behind you. But don't lose them in the town. once you have all the zombies from the town. Start going down the road that leads away from the town. Then you can Sprint away as fast as you can from the zombies. Still heading away from town. Once you've lost them all. make a large circle back. Making sure you do not attract them again once you lost them. And loot the town as you please.

Also a good place to find a melee weapon or backpack is at the Lighthouse, you may spawn there, you may spawn other side of map. but look for a long piece of land sticking out into the ocean. You will probably find it there.

(Hint: the map is a large U shape)